# What is the error I'm making when checking for substrings from a text file?

Tags: python, string, file-handling

I'm writing a python code to check if a line in a text file contains a particular substring and if it does I'm printing the line number of it. So far it has been matching the correct line numbers and the wrong line numbers as well and I don't know where I'm going wrong. I am aware that there are user functions to do this which are much more easy but I wanted to know what's wrong with the code I wrote

Here, str1 is the given substring, and myfile is the text file.

```
for myline in myfile:           
        line_num = line_num + 1
        count1=0
        i=0
        for i in range (0,len(myline)-len(str1)+1):
            match1 = True
            if str1[0]==myline[i]:
                j=1
                for j in range(1,len(str1),1):
                    if str(str1[j])!=str(myline[i+j]):
                        match1 = False
                        break
                    else:
                        count1=count1+1
                        if count1 == len(str1):
                            print(line_num)
```

Comment: The algorithm is far too complex. If you want to find `str1` in `myline`, then a simple `if str1 in myline:` is sufficient. And if you also need the line numbers, there's no need to count them yourself. Change the loop to `for line_num, myline in enumerate(myfile):`".

Comment: Yes, thanks @Matthias, I am aware of those alternatives as well. I wanted to just check where I was going wrong with this code. This code does take a lot of time due to it having a lot of loops.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason
The count1 variable wasn't getting reset to 0 if there was a mismatch.
Instead of this,

```
        for j in range(1,len(str1),1):
            if str(str1[j])!=str(myline[i+j]):
                match1 = False
                break
```

I should have written this,

```
        for j in range(1,len(str1),1):
            if str(str1[j])!=str(myline[i+j]):
                match1 = False
                count1=0
                break
```